# Coverage-Gutter on Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, coverage.py

I try to use Coverage-Gutters. But the documentation is quite complicated and I kinda don't understand on how can it be used. I already installed the extension but I tried a number of things and it seems to be not working. Is there anyone know how to use it?

Answer (score 2):

The gutters are based on coverage output file, for example the `coverage.xml` file.
Configure a coverage plugin, run your tests with the coverage plugin and let Coverage-gutters watch.

An example for a Django:

`$ coverage python manage.py test`

`$ coverage xml`

A generated `coverage.xml` has now been written in your project's root and your VSCode Coverage-Gutters should now be visible.